# Result of adding second to date is one minute off; workaround

Tags: swift, date, foundation

I'm adding a second to an instance of Foundation's date, but the result is off by an entire minute.

```swift
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")!

let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -62544967141.9)
let date2 = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(second: 1),
                          to: date1,
                          wrappingComponents: true)!

ISO8601DateFormatter().string(from: date1) // => 0019-01-11T22:00:58Z
ISO8601DateFormatter().string(from: date2) // => 0019-01-11T21:59:59Z
```

Interestingly, one of the following makes the error go away:

- round time interval since reference date
- don't add time zone to calendar
- set wrappingComponents to false (even though it shouldn't wrap in this case)

I don't really need sub-second precision in my code, so I created this extension that allows me to discard it.

```swift
extension Date {
  func roundedToSeconds() -> Date {
    return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: round(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
  }
}
```

I want to know this:

- Why does this error happen?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there any issue with my workaround?

Comment: But I do want wrapping in my case, at least in general. That is, if I added another second, it should wrap around to `0019-01-11T22:00:00Z`. Checking whether wrapping would occur for a given input is too complicated.

Comment: Please read what [wrappingComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date) actually does

Comment: I have read the documentation for this parameter. It is my understanding that for example if you add a day to Jan 31 the date will become Feb 1, unless you have wrappingComponent on, in which case it will become Jan 1. Wrapping components is exactly what I want and it has performed exactly how I would expect in all cases except this peculiar one. If I misunderstood the parameter, I'd love to learn how.

Comment: I think I have seen other issues where calendrical calculations behave unexpected for dates very far in the past. Do you really have to work with dates in the first century? Does the problem also occur with other dates closer to the present?

Comment: Do you have a functional requirement to support dates before 2000?  If not just ignore it, as this only occurs for negative reference dates.  Something in the difference between rounding negative and positive numbers is confusing the algorithm.  The trivial fix seems to be to discard the fractional seconds since you don’t need them anyway.

Comment: I can reproduce it with more recent dates but so far only with negative reference dates, e.g. `Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -1008899941.9)`, which is _1969-01-11T22:00:58Z_. I do have to support dates before that, but I do not need the fractional seconds. So I guess discarding those is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this error happen?

I would say this is a bug in Core Foundation (CF).

`Calendar.date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:)` calls down to the internal Core Foundation function [`_CFCalendarAddComponentsV`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/6b26ed1b8879497ea794d14583b4d59136fe8428/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFCalendar.c#L1270), which in turn uses the [ICU Calendar C API](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c461/ucal_8h.html). ICU represents a time as an floating-point number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, while CF uses a floating-point number of seconds since the NeXT reference date. So CF has to convert its representation to ICU's representation before calling into ICU, and convert back to return the result to you.

Here's how it converts from a CF timestamp to an ICU timestamp:

```
    double startingInt;
    double startingFrac = modf(*atp, &startingInt);
    UDate udate = (startingInt + kCFAbsoluteTimeIntervalSince1970) * 1000.0;
```

The `modf` function splits a floating-point number into its integer and fractional parts. Let's plug in your example date:

```
var startingInt: Double = 0
var startingFrac: Double = modf(date1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, &startingInt)
print(startingInt, startingFrac)

// Output:
-62544967141.0 -0.9000015258789062
```

Next, CF calls `__CFCalendarAdd` to add one second to -62544967141. Note that -62544967141 lies in the round one-minute interval -62544967200 ..< -62544967140.0. So when CF adds one second to -62544967141, it gets -62544967140, which would be in the next round one-minute interval. Since you specified wrapping components, CF isn't allowed to change the minute part of the date, so it wraps back to the beginning of the original round one-minute interval, -62544967200.

Finally, CF converts the ICU time back to a CF time, adding in the fractional part of the original time:

```
    *atp = (udate / 1000.0) - kCFAbsoluteTimeIntervalSince1970 + startingFrac + (nanosecond * 1.0e-9);
```

So it returns -62544967200 + -0.9000015258789062 = -62544967200.9, exactly 59 seconds earlier than the input time.

> Am I doing something wrong?

No, the bug is in CF, not in your code.

> Is there any issue with my workaround?

If you don't need sub-second precision, your workaround should be fine.

> I can reproduce it with more recent dates but so far only with negative reference dates, e.g. Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -1008899941.9), which is 1969-01-11T22:00:58Z.

Any negative `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` in the last second of a minute interval should cause the problem. The bug effectively makes the first round whole minute prior to time 0 span from -60.99999999999999 through -1.0, but it should span from -60.0 through -5e324. All more-negative round minute intervals are similarly offset.